# Close tab by double-click in Safari

Tags: safari, tabbed-browsing

How can I close a selected tab by double-clicking on the tab header in Safari?

Comment: Is this separate to the other question you asked; [How to close a tab by double-click in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/q/422053/97028)?

Comment: Yes, it's a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari doesn't support this functionality including extensions.