# Close tab by double-click in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, plugins

How can I close a selected tab by double-clicking on the tab header in Google Chrome?

The extension [Double-click closes tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/megplcpdkmjjoondippkedoaidkeikcm) only works on the page itself - not the tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Chrome Toolbox (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) and check "Double click on a tab to close it".

Comment: I have no this option after installing plugin on Chrome for MacOS X. But on screenshot I have saw it... Why?

Comment: @Altaveron: tested ! It's not available for MAC at the moment I think

Comment: @Altaveron: It says in the "Details" for the plugin that this functionality is not available on Mac and Linux.

Comment: Is it me, or can this extension no longer be installed in Chrome? I click on Add to Chrome, all goes well but it just doesn't install. Anyone else?

Comment: dead link - I want to only close a tab if I double click the "X" - otherwise I accidentally close tabs

Answer (score 0):

**UGChrome** have the feature built in

https://github.com/intika/UGChrome

Note that it's not yet available for windows